# Emberjs render destination view before transition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js

I have been using emberjs for quite some time now but have never quite worked out how I may entirely render a destination view before transitioning to it. A good example of this in the wild is how they do it at https://vine.co/ where it appears they are deferring a view transition until the destination view has been rendered.

I would like to replicate this functionality to give a better UX experience. I too have got a loading bar at the top of the page when loading in models but then the transition seems a bit jittery whilst ember builds up my DOM.

I have looked around at using the loading event that ember fires but don't really know what I am doing from there.

Any pointers on where to look in the API or how to do this would be great.